# Storing Images as Models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image, file-upload, paperclip

In the CMS of a site I'm building I'm using Paperclip to handle file uploads. Users can upload images and must give each image a brief description which is then used in naming the image (for SEO) and for the image's alt tag. Each Image is resized to a number of predefined sizes and stored on S3.

A user can utilise this image in a number of places, effectively creating multiple different types of model, each of which refers to a particular image.

So given that I need to store meta-data about the image (its description) and I need to share a single image between multiple models, it seems to make sense to encapsulate the image in a model of its own which can then be added as an association on any models that need it. The `Image` model then has Paperclip's attached file. This means I don't need to store duplicate information on any models referring to the image.

My concern is one of performance. Rather than hitting a URL directly as an attribute, any image requests now need to go through the `Image` model.

Is this a sensible solution or should I approach this in a different way?

Comment: What do you mean by hitting the URL directly? If you're using paperclip, then you're always going to access the link through the model e.g. `@user.avatar.url`

Comment: @claptimes So far as I'm aware, a Paperclip attachment is not a model and isn't persisted to the database. Check any migrations/schemas in a project that utilises Paperclip and you won't find a separate model. It is a temporarily class generated when a Model is instantiated. Storage takes place on the Paperclipped model so when I say 'directly' I mean directly hitting a model attribute rather than having to go deeper; to another model.

Comment: So are you saying `@item.image.url` vs `@item.image_url`?

Comment: @claptimes Exactly. The former incurs an extra database hit. I've made an edit for clarity.

Comment: I think you are thinking too much… locomotive does [something similar](https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine/blob/master/app/models/locomotive/content_asset.rb), although locomotive is using mongo not sql but that's not much different in term of IO operations. If you are building a CMS you probably wouldn't expose the actual `Image` model anyway. You would probably have it as some sort of asset name or meta key which will be resolved once the template is compiled. If lookup time is what you worry about then apply caching.

Comment: @j03w Yep. I suppose judicious caching would largely negate the extra hit. I'd be interested if you could expand on; ' If you are building a CMS you probably wouldn't expose the actual Image model anyway. You would probably have it as some sort of asset name or meta key which will be resolved once the template is compiled.'

Comment: hmm without knowing your full requirement it would be quite hard to specify it in details. Have a look around on how other CMS does think would probably give you a better idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are thinking of it exactly right. You want [Rails Polymorphic Associations, documented here.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) In fact, images are the use case used in the example.

Any performance difference will be negligible, and probably better than if you hand roll some other solution.